# Why doesn't my code print anything?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Why doesn't my code print anything when I press a radiobutton and then the submit button? For example, if I press the "Open Save" radiobutton, leave the entry blank and press submit it should print "test2", but it doesn't print anything no matter what I do.

```
def Saves():
    global saveordelete
    saveordelete = 0
    global savedname
    def openthesave():
        saveordelete = 1
    def deletethesave():
        saveordelete = 2
    def opensave():
        if saveordelete == 1:
            openname = savedname.get() + ".txt"
            my_file = Path(openname)
            if my_file.is_file():
                print("tes1")
            else:
                print("test2")
        elif saveordelete == 2:
            openname = savedname.get() + ".txt"
            my_file = Path(openname)
            if my_file.is_file():
                print("test3")
            else:
                print("test4")
    root = Tk()    
    root.title("Saves")
    root.iconbitmap("morseicon.ico")
    root.resizable(0,0)
    Label(root, text="Name:").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
    savedname = Entry(root, width=20)
    savedname.grid(row=0, column=1)
    Button(root, text="Submit", width=10, command=opensave, bg="aqua").grid(row=3, column=8)
    Label(root, text="Choose kind:").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
    Radiobutton(root, text="Open save", height="1", command=openthesave, value=1).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
    Radiobutton(root, text="Delete save", height="1", command=deletethesave, value=2).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W) 
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Value of `saveordelete` within `opensave`  function is always going to be `0` because when you are modifying the value within the `openthesave` and `deletethesave`, it is not updating the original variable instead creating the copy of variable within the function (with scope within that function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`saveordelete` is a local variable in the functions `openthesave()` and `deletethesave()`. They do not change the value of the global `saveordelete` defined in `Saves()`. Either mark it as `global` in both functions, or (better) use a class.